# tenses/ backshifting died/dies

Tags: tense, backshifting

> 1. I would love you till the sun **died**.
> 2. I would love you till the sun **dies**.

Are both of them grammatically correct? 
Is there a difference in their meaning?

Comment: Both work and invoke the subjunctive mood in different tenses, the past and the present.

Comment: @Varun the tags "grammar" and "meaning" are considered "bad tags" and probably should not be added to this question. Please be careful about adding them to future questions.

Answer (score -1):

"I would love you till the sun dies." - incorrect - impossible tense combination,

"I **will** love you till the sun **dies**." - correct - first conditional sentence - the speaker at least appears to be saying that this is a real possibility - an example of hyperbole!

"I would love you till the sun died."  -correct - second conditional sentence following the normal rules for the second conditional

This question came back: *Would love is present conditional. Why wouldn't it be compatible with dies?*

Let's analyse *when the sun dies* by substituting another expression. We know the sun will die one day so we are, in effect, stating a time like any other. So an equivalent substitution would be:

*I would love you until 6 o'clock.*

It is clearly incomplete. Let's think of a way of completing it:

*I would love you until 6 o'clock if you agreed (agree - see footnote) to pay my electricity bill.*

So we could say:

*I would love you until the sun dies if you agreed (agree - see footnote) to pay my electricity bill.*

The conditional sentences in English are strictly logical and entirely consistent with other aspects of grammar. Don't fight them - go with them!

Footnote: I have dealt with these two possibilities in another post and will not repeat the explanation here.

Comment: *would love* is present conditional. Why wouldn't it be compatible with *dies*?