# Question about sequence of tenses: inside "until" clause

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

> Mary says, **" I'll wait until you make your decision."**

Which would John say?

A) *"She said she'd wait until I **make** my decision."*

B) *"She said she'd wait until I **made** my decision."*

If they are both OK, is there any difference?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think John would say (A) if he has not yet made the decision, (B) if he is talking about the past and the decision was made some time ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["until something" in reported speech.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/161882/until-something-in-reported-speech) Also [tenses/ backshifting died/dies](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/77095/tenses-backshifting-died-dies) and probably others.